# data appended is not displaying in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

When i click on the following anchor tag

```
  <h4><a  [routerLink]="['/demo/article',article._id]">{{article.articletitle}}</a></h4>
```

,an article will be displayed (which is in another ts.file) but it is not getting displayed sometimes and in some cases on refreshing it displays.I think it is becasue of ngonint(),which displays only after refreshing?I am not sure about my problem.....can any one suggest help..........

article.ts,

```
  route.params.subscribe(p => { this.id = p['id'] });

     ngOnInit():any{
       this.showarticles = true;
       this.showform = false;
       var headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json')
        this.http.get(this.header1+'api/auth/getarticlebyid/'+this.id,{ headers: headers })
            .subscribe(
            response => {
                if (response.json().error_code == 0) {
                      this.articles = response.json().result;

                } else {
                    this.toastr.error('Old Password is not correct');
                }
            });
```

my template,

```
  <div class="col-sm-12 nopadding topmargin-lg" *ngFor = 'let article of articles'>
    <div class="form-group">  
        <div class="heading-block nobottommargin noborder">
            <h4>{{article.articletitle}}</h4>
            <span>{{article.articledescription}}</span>
            <h5 class="nobottommargin">{{article.tags}}</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thats strange. are u getting any errors in console?

Comment: I fixed it...........

Comment: may I know what was the issue?